# Alert box Bootstrap close button disappered

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is the desire output by clicking the button. there is a close button beside the text.

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Successfully Alerted</strong> 
</div>
```

This is my code. when i clicked the button the close button for alert box disappered.

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible w-50" style="display: none;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>

</div>
<button class="btn btn-info abtn">Alert</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    showAlert();
  });

  function showAlert() {
    $('.abtn').click(function() {
      $('.alert').addClass("alert-success");
      $('.alert').text("Successfully Alerted").show();
    });

  }

</script>
```

I am doing this because i want to show different messages depending on the situation with different color. any idea why this is happening and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of `.text` to have the `X` appear in your `alert` as well as the `text`

`.text()` will replace everything from your `alert` div

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.abtn').click(function() {
    $('.alert').addClass("alert-success");
    $('.alert').append("Successfully Alerted").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="alert alert-dismissible w-50" style="display: none;">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>

</div>
<button class="btn btn-info abtn">Alert</button>
```

Comment: @TinHtooZaw Happy to hear. Do not forget to accept the answer please to mark the question as resolved :)

Comment: @TinHtooZaw HI all good. You can accept my answer by clicking the grey checkmark in my answer  Thanks

Comment: @TinHtooZaw [How do I accept an answer on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)